# elm-brunch watch is missing some of my Elm file changes

Tags: compilation, elm, brunch

I'm uncertain if this is an issue with [Brunch](https://github.com/brunch/brunch) or [elm-brunch](https://github.com/madsflensted/elm-brunch) or some configuration detail I've screwed up. Frequently, when I change an Elm file in my project, the compilation will appear to run, but the result will show elm compiler errors that were fixed on the last save. The errors disappear if I quit and rerun the watch command. I'm not sure why this is happening or even how to narrow down the possibilities.

For setup details, I'm running it using [brunch-with-elm-and-electron](https://github.com/neurodynamic/brunch-with-elm-and-electron) as boilerplate. My brunch version is `2.9.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is ok. This is both brunch and elm-brunch issue. Brunch plugins are designed to compile each file separately on change. `elm-brunch`, however, runs `elm-make` for elm modules instead. That's why brunch cache is not being updated properly, causing redundant error messages.

Unfortunately, there is no quick fix, but we are looking into the problem. Here's the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1573) to track a progress. Thanks a lot, this is a good catch!

UPD: Here's the [pull request](https://github.com/madsflensted/elm-brunch/pull/30) that should fix the issue.

Comment: Could this issue also be related to elm-brunch giving me slow compile times with elm-make  taking 100 seconds+ ? It also hangs at compiling sometimes. https://gist.github.com/mcade/d1b1138172cdc9144075f2a95862cf97

Comment: @heartmo TBH, I doubt that this issue is related to yours. `elm-brunch` does almost nothing but runs an `elm-make` tool for specified main files. You could try running `elm-make` manually for your project and comparing the compilation times.

Comment: I copied the elm directory form my project to another folder and tried running elm-make on my Main.elm file and it compiled in seconds. Any ideas on how else I might troubleshoot?

Comment: I narrowed down the part in elm-brunch that was taking ages and it's when I invoke the `elmCompile` function https://gist.github.com/mcade/2ef820853116679beaf95e50a8e88b4a

Comment: @neurodynamic Hi, hope you're doing well. I've modified the elm-brunch in my own fork to fix the issue, could you please check it out to see if it works for you?

Comment: @neurodynamic Sorry, forgot to include the link. Here it is https://github.com/stelmakh/elm-brunch

Comment: @VolodymyrStelmakh Thanks! Just did some new work on my project with this, and have not seen this issue pop up once since switching to your fork. Seems to work!

Let me say also that your original response and your work on this has made me really glad about switching to brunch. If this is how helpful the community usually is, I'm happy to be a part of it :)

Comment: @neurodynamic I'm glad that it helped. Happy to have you on board :)